# ansible user module execute tasks success,but new password can not ssh to the host

Tags: ansible

I use ansible user module to update password of remote host,the output means success,but use new password can not ssh to the host,what is the problem?anyone give me some tips? tks

Comment: Can you share a little more details. You playbook for example. Also, are u using password based authentication in ansible ?

Comment: yes,i generate a batch of ip ,user,hashed password entry for ansible to invoke.

Comment: -
 hosts: all
 gather_facts: False
 tasks:
    - user: name={{item.key}}  update_password=always password={{item.value}}
      with_dict: "{{users}}"

Comment: Are you doing password based ssh or key based ssh. Also is it from ansible or manual ?

Comment: based upon password,this password i keep it in db,which can be quried, i am user password is not wrong.after ansible  updates,new password and old all can not ssh to the host.

Comment: Ok, got your problem.

Comment: Was my answer helpful david ?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that you provided the plain-text passwords to the user module in Ansible.

But it actually requires an encrypted value of the password. [See the password parameter here.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html)

**Here is what you were supposed to do:**

1. Encrypt your password first (you may use python passlib module).
2. Use the encrypted value in your Ansible script (in password parameter).

Comment: That method  find out the bug.It is because two ip are from the same machine,which means ansible update the password two times,so only the latter of them can  be used to ssh.thanks a lot to you .